# let declared variable can be declared or not

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Identifier 'a' has already been declared

can any one tell me why ?

```js
let a = 3;

function a() {
  let a = 1;
}
console.log(a);
a();
```

Comment: let a, function a() - change the name of either. Also the a in the function is known only to the function due to the let

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Comment: You defined a function with the name `a` and a variable with the name `a`.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

`let` makes a variable block scoped. All blocks opened within a block wherein `a` is declared know `a`.

Additionally, your first `a` and the function `a` are colliding.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you did this:

```
let a = function () {
  let a = 1;
}

let a = 3; // At this point you already have 'a' variable
```

Comment: You mean `window.a = function () {`

Comment: @mplungjan yup, I made a mistake here. But the main point is that 'a' is already declared

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're creating a function with the same name as an already created variable 'a', whether you can or not you really should never do that.

Secondly let allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. In other words, your function already has the variable 'a' declared.